# how to data fetch using json parsing in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am beginner of iPhone developer. I want to display data from server I have used below source code..

```
-(void)loadData:(id)sender
{
    self.requestdata=[NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kLatestKivaLoansURL]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    [requestdata setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [requestdata appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [connection release];
    self.requestdata=nil;

}

#pragma mark-
#pragma process loan data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    [connection release];
    NSString *responsedata=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:requestdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.requestdata=nil;
    NSDictionary *respDict = [[responsedata JSONValue]objectForKey:@"nodes"];
    NSLog(@"Response Dict:%@",respDict);
    NSMutableArray *arraY = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arraY = [respDict mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"My array:%@",arraY);
    NSString *mystr = [[[arraY objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"node"]valueForKey:@"field_company_name_value"];
    NSLog(@"Mystrname:%@",mystr);
    NSArray *latestLoans=[(NSDictionary *)[responsedata JSONValue]objectForKey:@"responseData"];
    NSLog(@"latest_dictionary:%@",latestLoans);
    DisplayViewController *disp=[[DisplayViewController alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i< [[latestLoans valueForKey:@"entries"] count] ; i++) {

       // Search *aSearches = [[Search alloc] init];

        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[latestLoans valueForKey:@"entries"] objectAtIndex:i];

       // disp.link=[tempDict valueForKey:@"link"];

        /*link = [tempDict valueForKey:@"link"];
        aSearches.title = [tempDict valueForKey:@"title"];
        aSearches.description = [tempDict valueForKey:@"contentSnippet"];
        [appDelegate.search addObject:aSearches];*/

        [appDelegate.disparray addObject:tempDict];
    }

    NSLog(@"DisplayArray:%@",appDelegate.disparray);
    [self.view addSubview:disp.view];
   /* DisplayViewController *disp=[[DisplayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:disp animated:YES];*/



}
```

Please give any suggestion or source code which is apply in my code

Comment: Please, could you put more readable code?

Comment: First explain to us what it does.  If you can't explain it, *what the heck are you doing using it?*

Comment: What problems are you having with this source code that you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/). It will do the job for you.

There is a specific method to handle JSON operations through the class [AFJSONRequestOperation](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html#//api/name/JSONRequestOperationWithRequest%3asuccess%3afailure%3a)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

http://json.org/

This is great tutorial for beginner, pls read this tutorial.